# how to include frontend javascript files to bundle webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, webpack-2

I need to bundle my front-end javascript files to bundle.js. 
here is my webpack.config file,

```
var path = require('path');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    target: 'node',
    entry:['babel-polyfill', './bin/run.js'],
    output: {
        path: './build',
        filename: '[name].min.js'
    },
    externals: nodeModules,
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compressor: {
                warnings: false,
                screw_ie8: true
            }
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                test: /\.js$/,
                include:/public/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
            }
        ],
        noParse: [/ws/]
    }
};
```

how can I include my front-end javascript files to the bundle ?

Comment: The Webpack config isn't where you specify the full list of files. Within your entry script, `./bin/run.js`, you'll want to `require` or `import` other files (and have those do similar for more files, etc. to form a dependency tree). Webpack has the options for this documented under "Concepts" – [Modules](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/modules/) and [Module Resolution](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/).

Comment: got it.. @JonathanLonowski thanks

Comment: now i am having error in jquery,
`
F:\master QMS - Copy\QMS\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js:31
                                        throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
                                        ^

Error: jQuery requires a window with a document
`

I tried with 
`        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        }),
`
 this block, no use @JonathanLonowski

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `webpack2` then you should know this change:

```
module: {
    rules: [ // <----it is been changed to "rules"
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
        }
    ],
    noParse: [/ws/]
}
```